# Iron Router LayoutTemplate displaying Extra Template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am new to MeteorJS and currently building an application that also utilises the iron-router package and unsure what I am doing wrong when it comes to iron router layouts.

I have defined the following within my main.js file:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
});
```

and the following within my main.html file:

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    {{> yield "navbar"}}
    <div class="container">
        {{> yield "form"}}
        {{> yield "main"}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Using the above info, I've added the following Router.route within my main.js file:

```
Router.route('/:_id', function () {
    this.render('navbar', {
        to: 'navbar'
    });
    this.render('website_details', {
        to: 'main',
        data: function() {
            return Websites.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        }
    });
});
```

I have also created a new template called **website_details** within my main.html file but when I run my app to display this Router.route to 'main', apart from displaying the navbar to 'navbar' and website_details to 'main', it is also displaying my 'form' as well, even though the above Router.route does not include this and do not understand why?

I basically assumed I would just see both 'navbar' and 'main' alone templates and not the 'form' template for this route.

Comment: What is the name of the template that is rendered for the "form" yield? I ask because IronRouter might be picking it up automatically.

Comment: this.render('website_form', {
        to: 'form'
    });

Comment: Any ideas on the above or do I need to provide further information?

Comment: I can't see anything on the code you have provided. What I would do is make absolutely sure that the functions and templates that I think are being used are being used (with `console.log`s in routes and "I'm website_form" in templates). If you can reproduce the problem by copying the relevant bits to a fresh meteor project and publishing it, we can dig in further.

Comment: @BudgieInWA - I will try what you have stated but is there any specific code that I can provide above that might assist you to what I could be missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really know where to look. A minimal repro (and the process of making one) should help though